# Скорость консоль порта

Tags: свич

Принесли на настройку свич edge-core es3510ma, но не могу найти скорость консоль порта, чтоб к нему подключиться.

Если кто-то знает скорость, отзовитесь! Буду премного благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

COM1 или COM2 speed 115200

сам спросил - сам ответил=)

Answer (score 0):

ну не обязательно... На кошках (Cisco) в стандарте 9600

Comment: на делах в основном тоже все 9600.а на edge-core es3510ma speed 115200. 9600 я пробовал в первую очередь.